# Atrribute Error: 'AlignConfig' object has no attribute 'encoder', 'PoolFormerConfig' object has no attribute 'encoder'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, attributeerror, huggingface

I am using** python==3.10, torch==1.13.0+cpu, transformers==4.35.0.** I am trying to (cpu)benchmark the transformer models in pytorch framework using the command:

`python run_benchmark.py --models kakaobrain/align-base --batch_sizes 1  --sequence_lengths 384`

when I execute the command, am getting the atrribute error as:

---

FutureWarning: The class <class 'transformers.benchmark.benchmark.PyTorchBenchmark'> is deprecated. Hugging Face Benchmarking utils are deprecated in general and it is advised to use external Benchmarking libraries to benchmark Transformer models.
warnings.warn(
1 / 1

**'AlignConfig' object has no attribute 'encoder'
'AlignConfig' object has no attribute 'encoder'**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/priya/priya/transformers/examples/pytorch/benchmarking/run_benchmark.py", line 50, in
main()
File "/home/priya/priya/transformers/examples/pytorch/benchmarking/run_benchmark.py", line 46, in main
benchmark.run()
File "/home/priya/miniconda3/envs/pyo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/benchmark/benchmark_utils.py", line 710, in run
memory, inference_summary = self.inference_memory(model_name, batch_size, sequence_length)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

---

I have encountered the same issue while trying to install the transformers package using pip as well as from the source code.
And the same issue persists in many transformer models. Hereby, am listing few of them:

1.kakaobrain/align-base
2.BAAI/AltCLIP
3.SenseTime/deformable-detr
4.sail/poolformer_s12
etc.,

Am I missing something ? and another question would be Is anybody tried without config file ?

I understand the deprecation of Hugging Face Benchmarking utilities. I'm curious if there are anyone who are still using or have information on alternative benchmarking tools. Is there a discussion or resources we can tap into regarding this issue?

I have also tried --only_pretrain_model args to avoid config file. but the encoder issue persists.

ISSUE:

**'AlignConfig' object has no attribute 'encoder'
'AlignConfig' object has no attribute 'encoder'**

Any assistance on this issue is greatly appreciated, thankyou!